# How to move through browser tabs using gestures in Mac OSX Lion?

Tags: osx-lion, gestures

I'd like to move back and forward through the tab collection in Safari (or Chrome or FF) using trackpad gestures.

Does this gesture exist?

Using a 3 finger swipe (left and right) nicely moves you through the history of the current tab, however, I can't find a way to navigate through the entire tab collection with gestures alone.

Comment: You could just do a 2-finger pinch-in then 2 finger scroll to change tab

Answer (score 3):

You can use [BetterTouchTool](https://folivora.ai). It should be available for Lion in the next few days when the developer gets round to upgrading it. You can specify ***loads*** of custom gestures, almost everything you can find to do, can be mapped to a gesture or a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Thanks Fred. I'm checking out BTT now. It seems Safari is the only browser that supports gestures out of the box. So, BTT will add custom gestures to Chrome and Firefox?

Comment: You can map gestures to key commands (so four finger swipe -> Cmd + Tab)

Answer (score 1):

Since Mac OS X version 10.5 ('Leopard'), you can use gestures to switch tabs in Firefox. Simply set browser.gesture.twist.left and browser.gesture.twist.right to Browser:PrevTab and Browser:NextTab in about:config.

The 'twist' gesture will now switch tabs in Firefox, assuming it isn't overridden by a global mapping in System Preferences > Trackpad.

Answer (score 1):

For Safari

1 - Pinch In (As like you are zooming out)

2 - Use two finger to swipe left or right

Works for me on Safari 7.0.3

Answer (score 1):

#### Firefox

Move from left to right in open TABS:

<kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>⌥</kbd>-<kbd>→</kbd>

From right to left:

<kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>⌥</kbd>-<kbd>←</kbd>

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question. Those commands are not gestures which the OP spcifically asked for.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. You'd have to bind a gesture to the keyboard shortcuts. Something like Better Touch Tool (when it's Lion ready) can do that.

Answer (score 0):

check out nextTab. http://nextab.chicheng.me/

Might be what you're looking for.